# Count number of MySQL rows

Tags: php, mysql, html

Im trying to count the number of rows in a MySQL database and report that number using PHP. I've read all the documentation and I think this piece of code should be working but no matter what I try, it fails.

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) ) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $q = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recepiants='$username' AND readcheck='T'";
    $count = mysql_num_rows($q);
?>
<div class="user_info">Logged in as <?php echo $username; ?> | <a href="admin.php">Add a post</a> | <a href="experiment.php">View Posts</a> | <a href="inbox.php">Message Center <?php echo $count; ?> </a> | <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></div>
<?php } else {?>
```

The script successfully reports `$username` but `$count` doesn't return a number. Any ideas? Am I missing a bracket or semi-colon somewhere?

Comment: `recepiants` - Is that how the column is spelled in your table?

Comment: Times like these that I wish I wasn't a native english speaker. Glad my mother didn't see that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing you're missing is running the actual query:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) ) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $q = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recepiants='$username' AND readcheck='T'";
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<div class="user_info">Logged in as <?php echo $username; ?> | <a href="admin.php">Add a post</a> | <a href="experiment.php">View Posts</a> | <a href="inbox.php">Message Center <?php echo $count; ?> </a> | <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></div>
<?php } else {?>
```

Probably better would be to run a `COUNT` in the query, if that's all you need:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) ) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM messages WHERE recepiants='$username' AND readcheck='T'";
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
    $count = $result['Count'];
?>
<div class="user_info">Logged in as <?php echo $username; ?> | <a href="admin.php">Add a post</a> | <a href="experiment.php">View Posts</a> | <a href="inbox.php">Message Center <?php echo $count; ?> </a> | <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></div>
<?php } else {?>
```

And, as someone else noted, you need an active database connection.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 8):

[mysql_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) expects a query resource – you're supplying a string. You need to perform the query before you can expect to know anything about its result.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recepiants='$username' AND readcheck='T'";
if(!$query = mysql_query($sql))
  trigger_error(mysql_error().' SQL: '.$sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

I suspect the above code will also generate an error based on your typo of 'recipients' in the query. Always check the return value of `mysql_query`.

**Edit:** As jeroen noted, if what you pasted is the entire code of that page then you have neglected to open a database connection. See [mysql_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and [mysql_select_db](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php).

Comment: aww you got me by 22 seconds. kudos

Comment: This is just a snippet, I am connected.

Answer (score 4):

You have not actually executed your query.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recepiants='$username' AND readcheck='T'";
$result = mysql_query($q);
if ($result) {
  $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong (there needs to be an actual query):

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recepiants='$username' AND readcheck='T'";
$count = mysql_num_rows($q);
```

it should be:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recepiants='$username' AND readcheck='T'";
$result = mysql_query($q, $connection);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are evaluating $q as a string, you're missing a mysql_query() on $q

Answer (score 2):

You've forgot to run the query.

```
$res = mysql_query($q);
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check apart from running the actual query:

1. is the column really called `recepiants` or is it perhaps `recipients`?
2. have you opened a database connection?

Answer (score 1):

The query is:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the simple code and I am sure it will work for many out there. Current code will check if vaule is already in the database, if it already exists will not add the record to database, if it never exists already will add the record to database.

```
<?php
    $chkval =52364; 

    $con = mysql_connect("servername","username","password");

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("databasename", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT column_name FROM table_name where column_name = '$chkval'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            echo "There are records";

        }
        else
        {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (column_name)
                VALUES ('$chkval')");

                                echo "record added";

        }
            mysql_close($con);

 ?>
```

Comment: Please do not include religious statements in your answers. Thanks. Besides that, selecting columns isntead of the `COUNT()` is a bad idea.