# Count rows in the output data sent by a function in php

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is in my function.php file

```
function getAllData()
{
  $sql="SELECT * FROM `student`";
  $query=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
      $data[]=$row;
    }
  return $data;
}
```

In my index.php, I do some task

```
$data=getAllData();
foreach($data as $row)
{
.
.Processing xx of xx records
.
}
```

I want to find out total number of rows that the query outputs and fill the xx in an echo statement . Please help me with the php syntax. I tried lot of syntax that I found on the Internet but either it echos blank (nothing at all) or it echos Array and not the exact count. Thank you.

EDIT: Yes, this question may already had an answer at [Count number of MySQL rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503966/count-number-of-mysql-rows) Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: http://php.net/count The PHP documentation should've been your first stop, along with the realization that most php functions are named to describe what the function does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count number of MySQL rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503966/count-number-of-mysql-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then it is as simple as:

```
$data=getAllData();
$counted = count($data);
$i = 1;
foreach($data as $row)
{
.
.Processing $i of $counted records
.
$i++;
}
```

And! I strongly recommend you to use PDO. Find documentation [HERE](http://php.net/manual/ro/book.pdo.php)

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: It was indeed simple and it helped. I am looking at the documentation too. Meanwhile I wanted to ask one more thing. On the browser screen, it echos 1 of 20, 2 of 30, 3 of 20 .... 20 of 20 one below the other. Is there a way to clear previous echos? Thank you.

Comment: This happens because you have that echo in the foreach statement... If you want a final result like "Processed 20 out of 20", you should put that in a variable and echo it at the end of the foreach like `foreach(){...} echo $processed;`

Comment: Actually the whole loop takes a very long time to complete. The intention is to put it in the foreach loop so that live processing can be seen. I am still searching and found few options like 1. ob_end_clean();  2. echo $i . " of " . $counted . " Records\r"; (carriage return) 3.running javascript document.body.innerHTML = '' but i am unable to get success so far. Can you help?

Comment: the best way to do this will be to use JS... you have to make a function that keeps sending those results... It sounds to me like some kind of progress bar: http://w3shaman.com/article/php-progress-bar-script take a look at that... maybe it will help :D Sorry but I am not good with JS :(